# How to sum two subsets

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces

This is an example from Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler:

Suppose that $U = \{(x, x, y, y) \in F^4 : x, y \in F\}$ and $W = \{(x, x, x, y) \in F^4 : x, y \in F\}$ Then $U + W = \{(x, x, y, z) \in F^4 : x, y, z \in F\}$

I don't understand how $U$ and $W$ sum to that. Can someone explain how this conclusion came about? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $u\in U$ and $w\in W$. Then $u=(a,a,b,b)$ and $w=(c,c,c,d)$ for some $a,b,c,d\in F$. Therefore
$$
u+w=(a+c,a+c,b+c,b+d).
$$
As $a,b,c,d$ are allowed to vary over $F$, this generates all elements of the form
$$
(x,x,y,z).
$$